# Generate a default CRUD UI when using Castle ActiveRecord (.net)

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord, crud

Is there any simple way to generate a default crud (given an entity) with activerecord (castle implementation) 
or something similar for NET?

There is something like this for RoR ( it think its called activescaffold)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default scaffolding support

You can see at http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/gettingstarted/scaffolding.html
It's useful for initial stages of development, but if you have complex mappings you will have to extend it.